# MySQL wont connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im having trouble with MySQLi.

Every time I run this code it returns an error on `line 13(mysql_select_bd())`.

I cant figure out where the problem is.

Code:

```
<?php

$conn_error = 'Could not connect';
$mysqli_host = 'localhost';
$mysqli_user = 'root';
$mysqli_password = '';
$mysql_db = 'a_database';

@$mysqli_conn = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_password);

mysqli_select_db('a_database', $mysqli_conn);

?>
```

Comment: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php - please take a look at the error handling in the examples. You need to check each step i.e. the return value of the every single mysqli_* function in your script or else errors like you've encountered will drive you nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an incorrect usage of the function:

```
mysqli_select_db('a_database', $mysqli_conn);
```

The connection must come first before the database name in the arguments:

```
mysqli_select_db($mysqli_conn, 'a_database');
               // ^ connection object, then database name
```

Alternatively, you could also do this:

```
$mysqli_conn = mysqli_connect($mysqli_host, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_password, $mysql_db);
```

Or the object oriented interface:

```
$mysqli_conn = new mysqli($mysqli_host, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_password, $mysql_db); // personal preference
```

Comment: *Ah yes*... indeed. It does come 1st.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes it does very easy to figure out whats wrong

Comment: I'm just wondering why OP has `$mysql_db = 'a_database';` to start with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my guess is, maybe when the OP, encountered the error, maybe changing it to a hardcoded string might work. so initially this was a variable at first. thats just a guess

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that you can do something like this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'a_database');
```